# combining between scripts

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

```
DriverId      OrderCount      OrderCountWhereNameIsNotNull
12               2                         2
13               1                         1
```

this is the current table which is being made by this code:

```
 public partial class Control : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OrderDataRepository rep = new OrderDataRepository();

        var results = rep.GetAllOrderData().
                      GroupBy(o => o.DRIVER_ID).
                      Select(g =>
                                new
                                {
                                    DriverId = g.Key,
                                    OrderCount = g.Count(),
                                    OrderCountWhereNameIsNotNull = 
                                                      g.Count(o => o.RECEIVE_NAME != null)
                                }).ToList();

        DataViewer.DataSource = results;
        DataViewer.DataBind();
    }

    }
```

instead of the table I need to take and print for each DriverId a progress bar as in this script:

```
  int OrderCount, OrderCountWhereNameIsNotNull;
System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableRow oRow;
System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell oCell;
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl oDiv;

while (true)
//loop through records
//do while not eof
{
    oRow = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableRow();
    oCell = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell();
    oDiv = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
    OrderCount = 200; //get value from DB, convert to meaningful width
    OrderCountWhereNameIsNotNull = 100; //get value from DB, convert to meaningful width

    oDiv.InnerHtml = "<div style='border: 3px solid black; width: " + OrderCount + "px;'>";
    oDiv.InnerHtml += Environment.NewLine + "  <div style='border: 0px; background-color: red; width: " + OrderCountWhereNameIsNotNull + "px;'>&nbsp;</div>";
    oDiv.InnerHtml += Environment.NewLine + "</div>";
    oCell.Controls.Add(oDiv);
    oRow.Cells.Add(oCell);
    tblData.Rows.Add(oRow);
}
```

**I cannot combine them, may be the script is not good...please help**

at the moment my main page is:

```
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="DataViewer">
        </asp:GridView>
    </form>
```

[image]

Comment: How about adding a TemplateColumn to your grid with a ProgressBar in it?

Comment: i need to use my code or some other code because that is not a progress bar - it has to show how much tasks every driverid have and how many he already done...so can you help me to connect my script to the code or help me with another code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably find it simpler to bind your grid to your dataset, rather than building a table that attempts to inject itself into a grid:

```
<asp:GridView ID="DataViewer" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <TemplateColumn>
            <ItemTemplate>
Put the code for rendering your progress bar here in pure HTML. 
When you come to a value that will come from a row in your data, do like this:
<div style='width: <%# Eval("OrderCount") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </TemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: do you know how using wntity frame work i can set my  <%# Eval("OrderCount") %> instead of <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="DataViewer">
        </asp:GridView>

Comment: ...what does Entity Framework have to do with the controls on your UI? `"OrderCount"` will be whichever column in your datasource contains your data.

Comment: how to set <%# Eval("OrderCount") %> to OrderCount from the code that i pasted where  OrderCount = g.Count()

Comment: i get error when using your code: Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCollection must have items of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlField'. 'TemplateColumn' is of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl